# I can't make a on click pop up using "Popup Domination" and wordpress theme

Tags: onclick, wordpress, popup

I have been going crazy over this....
I can't figure out where to put this code in the page, or what to change it to for a customizable button created from the word press theme.
It doesnt seem there is anywhere to put that code. 
[This is what they describe as the on click process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2yWb.png)

## 2 Here is what the code where the button is located looks like:

[code from the wordpress theme, the text editor side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgO6x.png)

am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Its visual composer short-code. does visual composer install with ur wordpress ?

Comment: please explain more detailed. the visual composer is part of the wordpress and is compatible with the theme I'm using. 
Im also using a third party site popup domination to try and attach the pop ups to the click button. 

are you saying that maybe this plug in isnt compatible with visual composer?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be working but for some reason an auto

appeared that might be the problem...
it also messed up with your "href=..." are you sure you did close the  properly?

[image: Your Website]

There's no css for popdom so even if it was right the popup will not appear, you have to find a way to delete these auto

tags, try to up the a tag around the entire column instead of the button. If it not works

let's start by trying to remove wpautop
put this in your functions.php

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

But sometimes the theme adds it again, so check your theme functions.php and look for things like this

```
"function mytheme_format($content) { "
```

and add the remove_filter inside it.

If you manage to make it work let's get back to your button, check again if your code looks like this:

```
[...something]<a class="example"> [button button attributes] </a> [...something]
```

You can search another solutions for this problem looking for "Tinymce autop" and "visual composer autop".

Comment: Thank you for replying!! This is exactly what I am trying to do. I did exactly that, but it didnt work :( I feel like I am missing something! any ideas?

Comment: It does not appear when you click right? But the html tag is showing if you use inspect element tool? Can you link your website or show your js and css for this popup?

Comment: no the tag doesn't show when inspect the element, i will include pictures in the original post